Is there a precise definition of "sentence mining"?
One of the frustrating aspects of language learning is imprecise definitions; here I'm interested in the definition of "sentence mining".  If we google it, we get:

Sentence mining is the process of finding new words from your immersion and making Anki cards to learn them.  (Refold)
Language learners refer to this practice of finding and drilling sentences as sentence mining.  (Unseen Japan)
That’s why I recently switched my focus from drilling vocabulary flashcards to collecting whole sentences using a technique known as sentence mining. By collecting hundreds of native sentences you can stop awkwardly cobbling together phrases using isolated vocabulary and instead improve your ability to say things the way Chinese people do.  (I'm Learning Mandarin)
Sentence mining is the technique of using sentences to study a language instead of words. ... You are essentially mining sentences and putting them in your brain. ... As for how you put the sentences in your brain you usually use a spaced repetition system.  (Medium)

So I'm getting the impression that "sentence mining" is just a fancy name for the obvious task of "writing down example sentences and revising them", and has nothing whatsoever to do with data mining as the name suggests.  Maybe there's more to this story, though.
Question: Is there a precise definition of "sentence mining"?

mining means finding them in different places, like Internet searches, for example. Or opening some long text and searching in that text.

Many of the sources on sentence mining describe two main steps overall: gathering the sentences and reviewing the sentences.
Depending on the source you read, the definition of sentence mining can refer to the first step of gathering the sentences or the step of reviewing the sentences or both.
In my opinion it makes most sense that the definition encompasses both steps since it doesn't really make sense to do one without the other.
Gathering the sentences
This involves reviewing various sources such as TV, books, films and conversations to get new sentences.
This can be defined as sentence mining, since you're mining these sources for new sentences in your target language.
Reviewing the sentences
This involves analysing the sentences on a regular basis, in order to learn information from them such as new words and grammar in a context rich way. Usually this would be done in an automated way with SRS software such as Anki or one that's more specialised for sentence mining such as Mandarin Mosaic.
This activity can be defined as sentence mining since you're mining the sentences for new information (new words or new grammar structures).
As stated, both of these steps are pretty specific and well defined. And as an overall definition of sentence mining, including both of these steps as the definition seems to make most sense, since to get the best benefit from the technique, you wouldn't really do one without the other.
